# why + in property of href in function .not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me please with the meaning of the plus "+" before and after myUrl in the function .not.

It works properly with + or with no +, so why the book used them??

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).after(' {' + href + '}');
    });

    //$('a[href^="http://"').attr('target','_blank');
    var myUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;
    $('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').not('[href^="' + myUrl + '"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I doubt that it works without the `+`. [`+` performs *string concatenation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()).

Comment: RTFM please, _+_ is the javascript concatenation sign..

Comment: definitely a syntax error without `+`

Comment: Sorry guys... you all right without +.+ it doesn't work, I just did a big mistake moving from local to the server for testing.
so '[href^="'+myUrl+'"]'  is equal to href="www.mydomain"
Correct??

Answer (score 0):

That is true. '+' was used only to concatenate the string.

The reason you might see it working without '+' could be because your browser app is able to directly post the value against '=' symbol (smart browser ehh!). Try without '+' in Microsoft IE to see it working differently ;).